# Отправка сообщений ботом телеграм

Tags: telegram, aiogram

Я создал бот магазин по продаже игровой валюты. Для того чтобы выводить её, ботаунужно отправлять смс админу.Вопрос заключается в том, как это реализовать?весь код был написан при помощи Aiogram.

Comment: Точно так же, как вы отправляете сообщения нормальным юзерам, так же отправляйте и админу, вам нужно только знать его ID

Comment: Спасибо большое